# iOS:convert integer data to byte format

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, arrays

i need to convert an given integer to the byte format .i.e as below .Is there any solution for this as i am new to iOS i found few links but not helpful .

```
       int year=24;
       Byte command[2]
       command[0]=/*  some thing that converted above*/
       command[1]=/*  some thing that converted above*/
       command[2]=/*  some thing that converted above*/
```

please help how to convert the above integer  value to the byte format if any sample code available.

Comment: In C the `>>` operator is shift right, and the `&` is bitwise-and. You can use these to extract bytes, e.g. `(a >> 8) & 0xFF` returns the second byte of `a`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this,

```
[NSData dataWithBytes:&myInteger length:sizeof(myInteger)];
```

Good luck.

Comment: can u place the code in the above comments i have given